# Commas at line end in Swift

Tags: swift

In swift the Xcode autocorrect keeps forcing me to add a comma at the end of my line, but I don't know why or what this comma is doing. What do commas at the end of a line do? I looked this up and found lots on comma use in a phrase to separate different values in a function for example, but nothing for why a comma could or would be used at the end of a terminating line of code. 
This is the code which Xcode wanted to add a comma to (the comma at the end is from Xcode):

```
var firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(playerArray.count)),
```

Is this just a glitch or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229844/comma-usage-in-swift

Comment: you are missing a parenthesis

Comment: why are people down-voting this? It's a legitimate question by a first-time user +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's a bug in Fix-It and the compiler's interpretation of your mistake. Your mistake is *really* that you've forgotten the final right parenthesis:

```
var firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(playerArray.count)))
                                                                         ^
```

But the compiler doesn't quite grasp that, and interprets it as a missing comma:

[image]

These messages might be improved in a future version of Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a close parenthesis ")" in your call, try this:

```
var firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(playerArray.count)))
```

Swift compiler is getting confuse and try to fix the wrong code by suggestion you a comma, however as you can see the compiler isn't always right!